# Impressão em Impressora Não fiscal

Tags: java, impressora

Pessoal para fazer a impressão em uma impressora Diebold estou usando o seguinte codigo:

```
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

    // Atributos de impressão do documento   
    HashDocAttributeSet attributes = new HashDocAttributeSet();

    // InputStream apontando para o conteúdo a ser impresso   
    FileOutputStream fil = new FileOutputStream("c.txt");

    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(fil);

    for (String keyItem : lista.keySet()) {
        p.print(keyItem + ": " + lista.get(keyItem).size() + " \n\b");

    }
    p.print(" \n\b");
    p.print("Total: " + lista.size() + (char) 27 + 'w');

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("c.txt");

    // Cria um Doc para impressão a partir do arquivo exemplo.txt   
    Doc documentoTexto = new SimpleDoc(fi, docFlavor, attributes);





    // Configura o conjunto de parametros para a impressora   
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printerAttributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    boolean mostrarDialogo = false;
    System.out.println(mostrarDialogo);

    if (mostrarDialogo) {
        // exibe um dialogo de configuracoes de impressao   
        PrintService servico = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 320, 240,
                controller.getConfiguracaoLocalController().getListaImpressora().getListaImpressora(), recebeImpressora, docFlavor, printerAttributes);

        if (servico != null) {
            DocPrintJob printJob = servico.createPrintJob();
            printJob.print(documentoTexto, printerAttributes);
        }
    } else {
        // Cria uma tarefa de impressão   
        DocPrintJob printJob = recebeImpressora.createPrintJob();

        // Adiciona propriedade de impressão: imprimir duas cópias   
        printerAttributes.add(new Copies(1));

        // Imprime o documento sem exibir uma tela de dialogo   
        printJob.print(documentoTexto, printerAttributes);

    }
```

Meu problema é, não consigo aumentar o tamanho da fonte, não consigo mudar a fonte, e sou obrigado a criar um arquivo txt para enviar para impressão. Eu consigo fazer de outra forma? costumo usar aqui Printable, mas não consegui fazer funcionar na DIEBOLD, mesmo instalando como impressora generic